# Is there any default type for produces and consumes Annotation in rest CXF

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, cxf-client

Below is the example I tried:

Service method declaration:

```
@POST
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//@Consumes({"application/xml", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/agentLogout")
public String agentLogout(String ext) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("status", "LoggedOut");
    return obj.toString();
}
```

Client side code:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(REST_URI);
client.path("agentLogout").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response agentLogoutResponse = client.post("3101");
String responseStr = agentLogoutResponse.readEntity(String.class);

try {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(responseStr);
    System.out.println("3101 DN--->"+json.get("status"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above example worked fine and produced the output as below:

> 3101 DN--->LoggedOut

My questions:

1. I haven't configured any type in produces and consumes in service method (as you can see I have commented it), however it executed well and produced the output - May I know how it is posiible?
2. Do we have any default type for produces and consumes?

Answer (score 2):

**Default is `*/*`**

**At Server Side**

At server side if you have not specified Content-Type it can accept any content-type provided by client. However if you have specific format JSON, XML etc, you need to specify the Content-Type so that CXF can invoke corresponding providers. In some cases where you have same REST path with different content-Type then it can select corresponding method based on Content-Type. In GET method if Content-Type is mismatched it will be ignored, but not in POST, it will throw 415 error.

**At Client Side**

Same applies to the client side as well, however generally we specify the accept type in case server can send multiple content-type, in this case we specify what content-type we can accept. so that server can send the data in specified content-type, generally when we expose REST we expose with JSON and xml type, during this case we need to send accept type to server, so that server can send either JSON or XML.